# Give the pdf of $T_1|N_1=2$ where $T_1$ is the time of first arrival

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, poisson-process

Give the pdf of $T_1|N_1=2$ where $T_1$ is the time of first arrival, and $(N_t, t\geq 0)$ is a Poisson process.

**Attempt:**

First find the cdf:

For $0<t<1$:
\begin{align}
P(T_1\le t\ |\ N_1=2)
&={P(T_1\le t,N_1=2)\over P(N_1=2)}\\
&={P(N_t= 1,N_1-N_t=1)\over P(N_1=2)}\\
&={P(N_t= 1)P(N_1-N_t=1)\over P(N_1=2)}\\
&={P(N[0,t]= 1,N(t,1]=1)\over P(N[0,1]=2)}\\
&={P(N[0,t]= 1)P(N(t,1]=0)\over P(N[0,1]=2)}\\
&={2\lambda te^{-\lambda t}\cdot \lambda(1-t)e^{-\lambda (1-t)}\over \lambda^2 e^{-\lambda}} \\
&=2t(1-t)
\end{align}
(then derive to find pdf)

This is wrong since the cdf must be non-decreasing? What has gone wrong?
My concern is that we can also have $0<T_1<T_2<t$

Answer (score 2):

I believe your concern has correctly diagnosed what went wrong.  To compute the cdf, try writing $\ P\left(T_1\le t,N_1=2\right)\ $ as $\ \int_\limits{0}^{\,t}P\left(N(s,1]=1\left\vert \,T_1=s\right.\right)\lambda e^{-\lambda s}ds \ $.

Comment: I do not see how to compute $\mathbb P(N(1)-N(s)=1\mid T_1=s)$, any tips?

Comment: Given $\ T_1=s\ $, the probability of $\ k\ $ arrivals occurring in the interval $\ (s, 1]\ $  (i.e $\ P(N(s,1]=k\,\left|\, T_1=s\right.)\ $ is $\ \frac{(\lambda(1-s))^ke^{-\lambda(1-s)}}{k!}\ $, where $\ \lambda\ $ is the expected number of arrivals per unit time. Just put $\ k=1\ $ in this expression.

Answer (score 0):

Following up on @lonza leggiera's hint, we have
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(T_1\leqslant t\mid N_1=2) &= \frac{\mathbb P(T_1\leqslant t,N_1=2)}{\mathbb P(N_1=2)}\\
&= \frac{\int_0^t \mathbb P(N(1)-N(s)=1\mid T_1=s)\lambda e^{-\lambda s}\ \mathsf ds}{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^2/2!}\\
&= \frac{\int_0^t \lambda(1-s)e^{-\lambda(1-s)}\lambda e^{-\lambda s}\ \mathsf ds}{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^2/2!}\\
&= \frac{2e^\lambda}{\lambda^2}\lambda^2e^{-\lambda}\int_0^t(1-s)\ \mathsf ds\\
&= 2\left(t - \frac{t^2}2\right)\\
&= t(2-t).
\end{align}